# Coercing a timestamp with millisecond precision that's cast as a character into a recognizable date-time object in R

Tags: r, date, datetime, timestamp, milliseconds

I have some `timestamp` values such as "2018-06-09 23:59:59.946" and "2018-06-09 23:59:59.938" that are being recognized as a character string in R at the moment and I need them to be treated as a date or date-time object.

Below is the relevant code chunk:

```
# Convert the timestamp from nanoseconds to millisecond precision
tradeOrders$timestamp = 
  as.POSIXct(gsub("D", " ", tradeOrders$timestamp))

tradeOrders$timestamp = 
  as.POSIXct(tradeOrders$timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")

tradeOrders$timestamp = 
  format(tradeOrders$timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")
```

Below is the same code but with `head(tradeOrders$timestamp)` & `class(tradeOrders$timestamp)` between each step and the corresponding output so you can see what's going on.

```
R> tradeOrders =
+   tradeOrders[order(tradeOrders$timestamp, decreasing = TRUE), ]
R> # Convert the timestamp from nanoseconds to millisecond precision
R> tradeOrders$timestamp = 
+   as.POSIXct(gsub("D", " ", tradeOrders$timestamp))
R> head(tradeOrders$timestamp)
[1] "2018-06-09 23:59:59 CDT" "2018-06-09 23:59:59 CDT"
[3] "2018-06-09 23:59:59 CDT" "2018-06-09 23:59:59 CDT"
[5] "2018-06-09 23:59:59 CDT" "2018-06-09 23:59:59 CDT"
R> class(tradeOrders$timestamp)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
R> tradeOrders$timestamp = 
+   as.POSIXct(tradeOrders$timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")
R> head(tradeOrders$timestamp)
[1] "2018-06-09 23:59:59 CDT" "2018-06-09 23:59:59 CDT"
[3] "2018-06-09 23:59:59 CDT" "2018-06-09 23:59:59 CDT"
[5] "2018-06-09 23:59:59 CDT" "2018-06-09 23:59:59 CDT"
R> class(tradeOrders$timestamp)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
R> class(tradeOrders$timestamp)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
R> tradeOrders$timestamp = 
+   format(tradeOrders$timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")
R> head(tradeOrders$timestamp)
[1] "2018-06-09 23:59:59.946" "2018-06-09 23:59:59.938"
[3] "2018-06-09 23:59:59.583" "2018-06-09 23:59:59.374"
[5] "2018-06-09 23:59:59.257" "2018-06-09 23:59:59.225"
R> class(tradeOrders$timestamp)
[1] "character"
```

I have viewed a few other answers regarding working with R and timestamps that have nanosecond or millisecond precision, which assisted me in generating some of the code above. But now I'm having difficulty transforming the output into a date-time. I've looked into solutions involving `library(nanotime)` as well as `lubridate` but am stuck.

Can anyone assist me?

Comment: You had them as a datetime, but the `format` made them into text. The milliseconds are there in the original `tradeOrders$timestamp`, they just don't get printed by default.

Comment: How can I have the millisecond precision print then? Is there an argument I need to set?

Comment: You can just use `format` if you need to look at them temporarily, or you can set a global option for the session - `options(digits.secs=3)` for example.